# TypeError: next expected at least 1 arguments, got 0 I am trying to iterate through csv file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following code to iterate through a csv file.  Iterate using the last column of in the csv file, column 11

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: next expected at least 1 arguments, got 0
```

The code is:

```
    from operator import itemgetter
import os
import csv

reader = csv.reader(open('file1.csv','rb'))
#header = reader.next()
header = next().reader
data = list(reader)
reader = None
data.sort(key=itemgetter(11))

writer = csv.writer(open('2.csv', 'wb'))
writer.writerow(header)
writer.writerows(data)
```

I think it is complaining about the header.

Comment: I think the commented line is correct, and the next one is wrong...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass `reader` as an *argument* to the [`next()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next):

```
header = next(reader)
```

or you could call the [`iterator.next()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#iterator.next) on the reader object:

```
header = reader.next()
```

I recommend sticking to the first spelling, especially since you can tell it to return `None` (or another default) if the CSV file is empty:

```
header = next(reader, None)
```